# EF - A referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am facing below issue while doing update operation on repository. We are using VS2015 and EF code first approach.

Have a class with foreignkey attribute and associated Navigation key.for e.g:

```
[DataMember, ForeignKey("SellerShopper")]
      [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The SellerShopperId value cannot exceed 32 characters. ")]
      public string SellerShopperId { get; set; }

 [Attributes.NavigationProperty]
      [DataMember]
      public virtual AuctionShopper SellerShopper { get; set; }
```

When we try to update sellershopperid in above class, it throws below exception:
A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'AuctionShopper.shopper_id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'RfpRequest.SellerShopperId' on the other end

I am trying to create global handler in repository base class where using reflection i want to check if property and its associated navigation key value is different, then make navigation property as null. By making it null, updates works fine. Please help making such global handler. I am not able to get navigation keys for particular foreignkey.

Looking  for some suggestions.

Thank You
SP

Comment: you need to show `AuctionShopper `

Comment: [Serializable()][DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
     [MetadataType(typeof( AuctionShopperMetaData))]
   [Table("aution_shopper")]
    public partial class AuctionShopper : EntityBase<AuctionShopper>
    {
    
      public  AuctionShopper(bool fieldTracking) : base(fieldTracking){} 
      public  AuctionShopper() : base(false){}
        [DataMember]
     [Key]
         public string shopper_i {  get{ ; }set { ;  }    
        }private string _shopper_id;

Comment: can't  you edit your question?